# In Shared Preference- Android I am not able to remove the error of "Private mode"

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Here I am Facing the error

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= MainActivity.this.getPreferences(getString(R.string.PREF_FILE),Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

I have al ready made this in `string.xml`

```
<string name="PREF_FILE">APP_PREF_FILE</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

Youre using it wrong the methods are

```
QBActivity.this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
QBActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("FILE",Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

you want to use the 2nd way.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.PREF_FILE),Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `getSharedPreferences()` instead. You are calling `getPreferences()` which has only one parameter.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.PREF_FILE),Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```